# XNA - check if Vector2 is inside Rectangle

Tags: vector, xna, xna-4.0

What's the best method to check if a Vector2 is inside a Rectangle?

myRect.contains(myVector2) does not work, because it expects a Point or a Rectangle.

I know I could cast the the Vector2 to a Point or even to a Rectangle with a size of 1/1, but I am unsure about performance.

What are your experiences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there may be additional execution time in casting vs creating a point like Point(myVector2.X, myVector2.Y), the implications are most likely too small for you to ever notice (generally should avoid premature optimization)

Go with whatever looks cleanest and easier to maintain. If it were me I'd probably just create the new point in the method call...

You could also write an extension method.

```
    public static Point Origin(this Vector2 v)
    {
        //original proposal
        //return new Point( (int)v.X, (int)v.Y );

        //better! does correctly round the values
        return new Point( Convert.ToInt32(v.X), convert.ToInt32(v.Y));
    }
```

Then you could do something like this `rect.Contains(vec.Origin)`

Something to remember, though: this method will not actually check if the vector is contained in the rectangle, this will only check if the origin is. Remember, a vector is direction **and** magnitude.

Comment: propably with that rounding, the performance is not the same as with casting. But stil I noticed nothing, when playing the game.

Comment: why do you need to use a custom function when the rectangle has a Contains method?

Comment: @xus because the contain method doesn't accept a vector2. So, to me at least, rect.Contains(vec.Origin) looks cleaner than doing rect.Contains((int)myVector2.X, (int)myVector2.Y)

Answer (score 5):

One of the overloaded versions of `Contains` for the `Rectangle` struct, takes an X and Y coordinate.

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(-5, -5, 10, 10);
Vector2 myVector2 = Vector2.Zero;

rect.Contains((int)myVector2.X, (int)myVector2.Y)
```

I assume you're talking about `myVector2` representing a point rather than a distance or direction.

Comment: No, I use a Vector2 to store the position. This can not be a Point! If it would be a point, translation(moving) of the according object wouldn't be smooth.

Comment: The answer you've excepted takes a Vector2, converts to a Point, and checks that against a rectangle. My method skips the step that converts to a point. I don't see the problem. If a Point isn't what you want, then why did you accept the answer that has you use a point. I'm not sure who is more confused here, me, or you. Especially when you just said you use a Vector2 to store a position, which makes it a Point. If you want to check that position against a rectangle, my method is about as efficient as you're going to find.

Comment: You'll need to cast your X and Y to an int as the Rectangle.Contains accepts integers, not floats.

Comment: @SwissCoder One of the things that Nic was (probably) alluding to was the fact that going from a vector position to a point loses accuracy as the point uses integers while the vector2 uses floats. So if you vector is at 2.4, 2.4 casting as int to check in a rectangle will force the points to go to 2, 2.  Just keep that in mind with whatever solution you decide to implement.

Comment: @Nic: My question was about the conversion. And you did not even notice a conversion was necessary. Also directy casting to int isn't the best solution.

Comment: @justnS: You are right. Check out my comment, to see why I unmarked your answer as the correct one.

Comment: Indeed, rounding to the nearest int would be more accurate than casting, which effectively rounds down.